# Why 1px padding around image renders different in major browsers?

Tags: css, cross-browser, padding

I have a span with an image inside.

The span has a border of 1 px and a padding to give a small gap between the span and the image but the 1px padding is rendered different in all browsers and i am not getting the best way to fix this issue.

the span has a display: inline-block because next to it there must be another element but i noticed if i change the display to block could look better.

```
<td class="tdCartCol4">
   <span>
       <img src="/medias/sys_master/loropiana/photosOfColors/hash000/8814966046750.jpg">
   </span>
   <p> W538 </p>
   <br>
   <i>blue navy </i> 
</td>
```

CSS

```
span {width: 17px;
height: 17px;
padding: 1px;
margin-top: 4px;
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 1px solid #b76e4d;}

img {
width: 17px;
height: 17px;
border-radius: 50%;

p {
font-size: 15px;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 5px;
}
}
```

Chrome

[image: Chrome]

Firefox, even in the same file with two equal settings they look different

[image: Firefox]

Comment: Well if you are using _fractions_ of pixels, you should not wonder too much about that ...

Comment: my bad is actaully 1px not fractions but thanks

Comment: Likely a sub-pixel rendering issue nevertheless ... The browsers themselves operate with such fractions internally, for example for calculated line-height you’ll see such values often in inspector ... so if Firefox paints one of those circles beginning on a “full pixel”, and the other somewhere in between two pixels, then such effects are often the result. http://www.unumux.com/ux-insights/2016/2/24/subpixel-troubleshooting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of doing the same thing twice (border-radius, height and width on the span and on the image) why not do it one go?

remove all styling from the span and use:

```
img {
width: 17px;
height: 17px;
border-radius: 50%;
padding: 1px;
border: 1px solid #b76e4d;}
```

This will render (as far as I tested) correct in different browsers.

I would advice to give the img a class and do the styling on that class 
 else all images will be round.